# submitting form to PHP page without reloading using the submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Hello friends please am new to jquery and javascript so i copied the code I want to send form to a php page without reloading the page, this code works but i want to click the submit button to send the form and not the enter key:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"  /><br><br>
<input type="text" id="job" name="job" /><br><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#name').focus();
        $('#name').keypress(function(event) {
            var key = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if (key == 13) {
                var info = $('#name').val();
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "fell.php",
                    data: {
                        name: $('#name').val(),
                        job: $('#job').val()
                    },
                    success: function(status) {
                    }
                });
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: did you try $('#name').keypress(function(event){event.preventDefault()})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the click of the submit button work you should wrap your code in a `form` element then change your JS code to hook to the `submit` event of that form. Note that will also give you the 'submit on enter keypress' action by default, so your current keypress handler can be removed. Try this:

```
<form id="my-form">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"  /><br><br>
    <input type="text" id="job" name="job" /><br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#name').focus();
        $('#my-form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "fell.php",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(status) {
                    console.log('AJAX call successful');
                    console.log(status);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Then what makes you believe it is not submitting?

Comment: it's not inserting into my database

Comment: <?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die ('error');

mysqli_select_db($con, 'test') or die ('error');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $job = $_POST['job'];
 
 mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tester VALUES('', '".$name."', '".$job."')");
 
}

?>

Comment: In that case you should post a new question about your PHP code. The AJAX part, which this question was about, is now working correctly.

Comment: @KingKanayoAustinLengend this answer should work, the problem is your PHP, seems you're looking for `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` which isn't set. Try adding `name="submit"` to the submit button.

Comment: Also, you are open to SQL Injection attack if that's how you are inserting records into mysql db.

Answer (score 0):

```
You are not name the submit button. Try to give name to submit button and try below:-
<form id="myFrom" onsubmit="submitForm();">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"  /><br><br>
    <input type="text" id="job" name="job" /><br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#name').focus();
    });
    function submitForm(){
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "fell.php",
            data: $("#myFrom").serialize(),
            success: function(status) {
                alert("successfull");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Using `on*` attributes is very outdated. You should use unobtrusive JS to attach events instead.